# Cannot parse rosbag in MATLab?

Tags: matlab, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just cannot parse this bag file.
So far the matlab code just looks like

filepath =fullfile(~/xxx.bag)

bagselect =rosbag(filepath)

the error on the second line is:
"Expected a connection record header, but instead found Chunk. Cannot parse the file."

I know the file isn't corrupted, I can read the point values in terminal.

It's just LiDAR data off of a velodyne puck. it's not compressed, is 4GB just too big for it to read? There doesn't exist any documentation for errors this early on in the process, so I'm pretty much in the dark, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251846/cannot-parse-rosbag-in-matlab?/) by [roonocerus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29022/roonocerus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you post the full error message in matlab? My first guess is that Matlab does not know how to convert the data into Matlab data type. So you need a way to convert ros bag data into Matlab data type. Have you looked into custom ROS message support?
https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ug/ros-custom-message-support.html

---

Originally posted by [snehesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31342/snehesh/) with karma: 31 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0